# How to use Launchctl for runing scheduled command

Tags: mojave, catalina, launchd

I try to work with `Launchctl` and have a question:

I know there is a possibility to run commands directly (shell for example) with Launchctl, can someone please add an example on how can I do it with delay? (for example, run the command echo 1 > /tmp/1 in 10 minutes)

I know it can easily be done by creating Launch Agents, I looking for a way to do it using Launchctl directly to programmatically.

I know I can run:
`launchctl submit -l my_choosen_name mkdir /tmp/mydir` as a direct command, my question is how can I schedule this to run every 5 minutes directly from `launchctl` ?

Comment: Could you call a script and put the delay there?

Comment: `launchctl` interfaces with `launchd` to manage and inspect daemons, agents and XPC services. Suggest you read the _manual pages_ for `launchd` and `launchd.plist` as well as for `launchctl`. In **Terminal**, use e.g. `man $command` where `$command` is one of the previously mentioned _commands_.

Comment: @lx07 no, looking for a direct command, not running a script with delay in it